# elasticsearch is not indexing from logstash.conf

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash, logstash-grok

i'm new to elasticsearch this is my logstash.conf file

```
input {
   #stdin {}
  file {
    path => "/demo_logs/2015-12-14.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
     csv {
        columns => ["data_date", "ip", "method", "status", "time"]
        separator => ","
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        workers => 1
}
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

i have triggered the conf file using /bin/logstach -f logstash.conf
loggstash started and no process about open the file and indexed in elasticsearch

so i just did un comment the stdin{} for getting the input in terminal as below

```
input{
       stdin {}
       #file {
        #path => "/demo_logs/2015-12-14.txt"
        #start_position => "beginning"
      #}
}
```

again i have run the conf file and insert the value as

> `2015-12-14 07:29:24.356302,127.0.0.1,get_names,exit,0:00:00.298635`

its show error as

```
Trouble parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"", :exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `each_index' for nil:NilClass>, :level=>:warn}
```

can anybody help in this two thing to successfully execute logstash.conf file from a .txt file and indexing all the values in that .txt file successfully.

i too tried with grok filter but i could not make it, if its grok filter also great for me

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Logstash are you using?

Comment: What about using elasticsearch_http instead of elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be mainly due to the fact that your data contains blank lines. If it's a log file you can open it in notepad++ and go to edit->line operations->remove blank lines. Hope this helps